# Scoring function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

I am trying to make a function that adds up two ints in an array from an inputted number to another. So for example the array is

```
int arr[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};
```

and the user inputs 18 and 2 so the program will add up the numbers from the first number (18) and stop once it gets to 2.

I tried looping, but it keeps returning an error:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

```
int cw(int first, int second ){
    int scoreCw;
    int arr[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};

    for (int i = first; i < 20; ++i)
        if(i != second){
            scoreCw += arr[i];
        }
    return scoreCw;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your `scoreCW` variable is declared but not initialized.

Comment: Not sure why you get SIGSEGV, but I think you actually want `if(arr[i] != second)` instead of `if(i != second)` and then also an `else break;`.

Comment: Are you starting at `arr[first]` or are you starting at `arr[n] == first`?

Comment: Also, how do you know that there are 20 elements between `first` and `second`?  You should probably `break` when `i == second` (or is that `arr[i] == second`).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your described scenario, `18` and `2` are NOT array indexes, but the code is treating them as if they were. `18` is located at index 2, and `2` is located at index 8. So, start at index 0, find the element with value `18`, then keep looping, now counting, until you find the element with value `2`, eg:

```cpp
int cw(int first, int second) {
    int scoreCw = 0;
    const int arr[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};
    const size_t num = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); // or std::size(arr)

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == first) {
            do {
                scoreCw += arr[i++];
            }
            while ((arr[i-1] != second) && (i < num));
            break;
        }
    }

    return scoreCw;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/swoFO6)

Alternatively, using standard C++ algorithms:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

int cw(int first, int second) {
    const int arr[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};
    auto arr_end = std::cend(arr);
    auto f = std::find(std::cbegin(arr), arr_end, first);
    auto s = std::find(f, arr_end, second);
    if (s != arr_end) ++s;
    return std::accumulate(f, s, 0);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/tpx9UA)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
int cw(int first, int second){
    int scoreCw = 0;
    bool need_to_sum = 0;
    static const int arr[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};
    for (int i =0; i<20; i++){
        if(arr[i] == first) need_to_sum = 1;
        scoreCw += (arr[i] * need_to_sum);
        if (arr[i] == second) break;
    }
    return scoreCw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an ambiguity between whether `first` and `second` are values in the array or indices, let's assume they are values.

```
int sum_range_values(int first_value, int second_value)
{
  int sum = 0;
  static const int arr[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};
  // Find first value in the array.
  int first_index = 0;
  for (first_index = 0; first_index < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); ++first_index)
  {
      if (arr[first_index] == first_value)
      {
          break;
      }
  }
  if (first_index >= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)) return sum;
  // Sum up values until the second value is found.  
  for (int second_index = first_index; second_index < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); ++ second_index)
  {
      sum += arr[second_index];
      if (arr[second_index] == second_value) break;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another twist on @Onyambu 's answer, hopefully also a bit simpler.

I've modified your array to test we only stop counting once the sequence `first`-`second` is found (or `first` - end of array):

- adding a `second` before `first`: `2, 18, 4, 13...`.
- adding a `first` after `second`: `10, 15, 2, 18...`.

```cpp
int cw(int first, int second)
{
    int scoreCw{0};
    int arr[] = {20, 1, 2, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 18, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5};

    bool counting{false};
    for (int n : arr)
    {
        if (n == first and not counting) { counting = true; }
        else if (n == second and counting) { break; }

        scoreCw += (counting ? n : 0);
    }

    return scoreCw;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j41x184Gr)